# Dynamic percent change indicator on bar chart DAX/Power

Tags: powerbi, dax, percentage, column-chart

I'm looking to add a dynamic percent change indicator that will display the percent change of values between two years of data within the same category.

The user is able to select two years using a slicer to compare values within categories. The range of years able to be selected is 1990-2021. There are four categories that I would like to display percent change for.

I have included a rough format diagram for context.

Thanks for any help

[image]